# Table with missing <tr> around a row: can I parse it?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr> <th> header1 </th> <th> header2 </th> </tr>
    <th> missing1 </th> <th> missing2 </th>
    <tr> <td> data1 </td> <td> data2 </td> </tr>
</table>
```

and I specifically need to access the row with "missing" in it.  Is there any way to access that row?  This table renders just fine in a browser, so I expected BeautifulSoup to find it, but `b.findAll('tr')` misses it.

EDIT: a specific, much more complicated example: http://atlasgal.mpifr-bonn.mpg.de/cgi-bin/ATLASGAL_SEARCH_RESULTS.cgi?text_field_1=AGAL010.472%2B00.027&catalogue_field=Sextractor&gc_flag=  specifically the table headed with 'Line Transition' spanning a few columns

Example of the specific problem:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://atlasgal.mpifr-bonn.mpg.de/cgi-bin/ATLASGAL_SEARCH_RESULTS.cgi?text_field_1=AGAL010.472%2B00.027&catalogue_field=Sextractor&gc_flag=').content)
table = r.select('table:nth-of-type(5) tr')
```

`table` is missing this row (which is contained in the source): `r.select('table tr')[19]`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the point

Comment: About your update: You are not using `html5lib`, and whatever parser I use, the 20th row (`r.select('table tr')[19]`) is **not** a row from the 5th table. If `r.select('table tr')[19]` is part of the HTML tree but not part of a specific table, **it is still part of the parsed HTML** and your expectations of what table it is in are wrong. Use `.parent` links to find out what table it *is* part of.

Comment: I accidentally left out the `html5lib` part, but thanks for `.parent`.  It turns out the row I'm looking for is not found at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the parser how this is handled. The HTML is broken, and although HTML parsers will do their best to represent the data anyway, how they do so is not defined by any standard.

BeautifulSoup can use [different parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use); by default the built-in Python standard library parser is used. If you install `lxml`, it's parser is used instead. You can also use the `html5lib` external module:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> broken = '''\
... <table>
...     <tr> <th> header1 </th> <th> header2 </th> </tr>
...     <th> missing1 </th> <th> missing2 </th>
...     <tr> <td> data1 </td> <td> data2 </td> </tr>
... </table>
... '''
>>> BeautifulSoup(broken, 'html.parser').select('table tr')
[<tr> <th> header1 </th> <th> header2 </th> </tr>, <tr> <td> data1 </td> <td> data2 </td> </tr>]
>>> BeautifulSoup(broken, 'lxml').select('table tr')
[<tr> <th> header1 </th> <th> header2 </th> </tr>, <tr> <td> data1 </td> <td> data2 </td> </tr>]
>>> BeautifulSoup(broken, 'html5lib').select('table tr')
[<tr> <th> header1 </th> <th> header2 </th> </tr>, <tr><th> missing1 </th> <th> missing2 </th>
    </tr>, <tr> <td> data1 </td> <td> data2 </td> </tr>]
```

As you can see, the `html5lib` parser included the row with the `missing` text in it in the tree:

```
>>> BeautifulSoup(broken, 'html5lib').select('table tr:nth-of-type(2)')
[<tr><th> missing1 </th> <th> missing2 </th>
    </tr>]
```

If you need to look for a specific table by caption, perhaps search for the caption first, then navigate to the parent table:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://atlasgal.mpifr-bonn.mpg.de/cgi-bin/ATLASGAL_SEARCH_RESULTS.cgi?text_field_1=AGAL010.472%2B00.027&catalogue_field=Sextractor&gc_flag='
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')

table = soup.find(text='Fitted Parameters for Observed Molecular Transitions').find_parent('table')
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    print row
```

Comment: Can you explain why `select` and `findAll` behave differently in this case?  While `select` recovers the missing row, it extracts all rows from all tables, losing information about the parent table.  `root.select('table')[0].select('tr')` works for the contrived example I used, but not for a more general case.  It's possible that there's another unclosed table somewhere above...

Comment: @keflavich: `select` uses CSS syntax; it will find all rows in all tables. You could use `table:nth-of-type(1) tr` to limit it to the first table only, for example. `find_all()` can look for all table objects, and then you'd have to loop over those to then search for all rows; it has its own uses (like using functions to search, etc.).

Comment: Thanks - this is pointing me in the right direction, but in the particular case I'm looking at (now linked in the question), `r.select('table:nth-of-type(5) tr')` still misses a row that `r.select('table tr')` finds.

Comment: @keflavich: sorry, forgot to use the `html5lib` parser, testing again.

Comment: @keflavich: still, the 20th row (index 19) is from the *Observed Spectrum* table. Use `r.select('table tr')[19].parent.parent` and see.

Comment: I learned enough from this to get to a decent hack, so I'm accepting rather than leaving it unnecessarily open, but the table I was looking for has the caption `'Ammonia Fit Parameters '` and still hides the `<th>` row.  Anyway, thanks for the extensive help!